# Accessing scorm data/package

Tags: javascript, jquery, sql-server, ajax, scorm

I have to build something or other to consume data collected via a Captivate training/quiz configured with scorm output. I've done some research on the LMS interaction with scorm and can't quite seem to wrap my head around it. I mean I know scorm is kind of an outdated standard and most solutions I've seen are more or less ploys to point one in the direction of excessively priced licensing.

When I try to run one of the training files, I get the following error when advancing slides - 'g_objAPI' is null or not an object. From what I've gathered from reading I assume that I need to construct scripting to instantiate that object via one of the LMS proprietary functions -

```
LMSInitialize()
LMSFinish()
LMSGetValue()
LMSSetValue()
LMSCommit()
LMSGetLastError()
LMSGetErrorString()
LMSGetDiagnostic()
```

But I have a feeling, or am being led to believe that there's more to it than that. I can't just interact with scorm? Or know when an event is fired there I can port the data through one of my processing functions. Or is it really as simple as accessing this g_objAPI upon completion of the presentation? Reading some of the reference out there really doesn't get into that. I mean I can add a js to the manifest, but what's accessible that can be consumed? I know there's a lot out there espousing the use of this standard, but it's not a very modern standard considering its most recent incarnation is 2004, and wasn't this designed before the advent of ajax, jquery, and other technology? It seems kind of an archaic design model. Sorry got a little frustrated at the end.

Comment: Well considering some of the legwork for the SCORM coding is done for me already by the Captivate app in the scorm_support.js so writing a few more lines of code beyond doesn't really bother me. Of course Google provides with varying tangents of research, but I think I've gotten it boiled down to why isn't the API isn't being set (when the code appears to be doing so) and will accessing the API upon completion of the .swf presentation provide all the values as an aggregation, or does it have to be accessed through the progression of the slides?

Answer (score 0):

SCORM is a standard, it doesn't impose using any specific technology (although it implies javcascript and almost every implementation is in javascript). I myself have used SCORM in conjuction with ajax and many js frameworks (jquery, prototype) successfully. So it's old, but not obsolete. Version 1.2 is also extremely successful and very widely used (unlike SCORM2004).

Having said that, it is rather complex to build a SCORM player. At the very least, you need to implement an API object with the functions you mention. For example:

```
function API(){}
window.API     = API;
API.LMSInitialize     = LMSInitialize;
API.LMSFinish         = LMSFinish;
API.LMSGetValue       = LMSGetValue;
API.LMSSetValue       = LMSSetValue;
API.LMSCommit         = LMSCommit;
API.LMSGetLastError   = LMSGetLastError;
API.LMSGetErrorString = LMSGetErrorString;
API.LMSGetDiagnostic  = LMSGetDiagnostic;

function LMSInitialize() {
//...do your SCORM-compatible stuff
}
```

In order to implement the complete SCORM standard, including the object model, you literally need to write thousands of lines of code (I know because I've done that)

I would suggest that you have a look at open source LMSs o projects that include a SCORM player, to get an idea of what you need to do (or, if their license approves it, use their code as is)

Comment: I can't really use an open source LMS because the nature of the infrastructure I'm forced to use. I'm essentially trying to access results from a Captivate generated SCORM package. I get what you're doing above with the API, but I see in the scorm_support.js that there a series of JScript functions that look for and try to initialize an API object. Unfortuneately, like my post said above the g_objAPI which it tries to put the API stuff into is always null. I'm wondering if what's missing is a block of code like yours above to create the window.API values so it can be assigned to the g_objapi?

Comment: yes, a scorm content always looks for the API first, in its parent/opening window. So you must publish an object called "API" that will hold all these LMS* functions